# No storage has been registered for component type

Tags: swift, realitykit

I made a custom component and made sure to call `registerComponent()` before instantiating an Entity that uses this component. Even after registering my component before use I am still getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and the old
***"No storage has been registered for component type 3445452219525568944(ARSDKPrototypePlatform.ManagedARObjectComponent) "*** error

I have a component and protocol

```
struct ManagedARObjectComponent: Component, Codable, Equatable {  
    var isDeployed = false  
    var id: Int  
     
    public static func == (lhs: ManagedARObjectComponent, 
                           rhs: ManagedARObjectComponent) -> Bool {  
        return lhs.id == rhs.id  
    }  
}  
  
protocol HasManagement {  
    var managedObject: ManagedARObjectComponent { get set }  
}
```

and when I instantiate the ARView I register this component

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {  
         
    let arView = sessionDelegate.arView  
          
    // Configure the AR session for horizontal plane tracking.  
    let arConfiguration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()  
    arConfiguration.planeDetection = .horizontal  
    arView.session.run(arConfiguration)  
         
    ManagedARObjectComponent.registerComponent()  
    return arView        
}
```

I have a class that conforms to the `HasManagement` protocol

```
class AREntity: Entity, HasModel, HasCollision, HasAnchoring, HasManagement {  
    var managedObject: ManagedARObjectComponent {  
        get { components[ManagedARObjectComponent] ?? ManagedARObjectComponent(id: -1) }  
        set { components[ManagedARObjectComponent] = newValue }  
    }  
    
    init(id: Int) {  
        super.init()  
        self.managedObject = ManagedARObjectComponent(id: id)  
        // ... more initialization code  
     }  
}
```

I tried registering it in the function where I first instantiate the `AREntity`

```
@discardableResult  
func generateBox() -> AREntity {  
    ManagedARObjectComponent.self.registerComponent()  
    let entity = AREntity(id: UUID().hashValue)  
    arView.scene.addAnchor(entity)  
        
    return entity  
}
```

I still get the error I still do not see this component when I `po` the components on the object itself.

With such scant documentation, I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.